Network request failed from my mobile device
I am developing a mobile app using React Native and axios for network request.
When I send Post request it says [TypeError: Network request failed]
But when I send same request from Postman it works. But in Postman it show an error call 'unable to certify the first certificate'.
How can I fix this and why I can not access from mobile.
This is my axios request to api
axios.post(path, {
  apiToken: loggedToken,
       pf: loggedpf
   }).then(function(response) { 
       if(response.data.msg==1){
           setprofilePic(response.data.profile[0]['Epic'])
           setisLoading(false);
           setdataSource(response.data.profile);
       }
       else if(response.data.msg==2){
           showError(response.data.message);
           navigation.navigate('auth');
        }
        else if(response.data.msg==0){
           showError(response.data.message);
        }
   })


Most likely the SSL certificate for your API server is invalid. Clients may decide differently how to proceed in such a case - axios seems to refuse talking to a service presenting an invalid certificate (which is the right thing to do in a production situation), and Postman continues but reports the problem (which is ok in a development situation). Fix your cert!

@Hans-MartinMosner  Thank You very much for your comment. Error has Fixed now. As you mentioned SSL Certificate is the reason for the issue.
